# Copy file using sudo access

Tags: 14.04, command-line, sudo, chown, cp

How I can copy file or folder for other user.
New file or folder must have his name.

I have sudo access for cp command

```
USER1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp
```

I am trying following command:

```
USER1@ySERVERNAME:HOME_PATH$ sudo -i -u USER2 cp file1 file2
```

I got an error:

```
Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c cp file1 file2' as USER2 on SERVERNAME.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

You should remove the `-i` from the `sudo` command:

```
sudo -u USER2 cp file1 file2
```

**Explanation:**

The problem you are facing is that your `sudo` access is limited to `/bin/cp` and using `sudo -i` required extra `sudo` permissions which you don't have.

As specify in the the error:

> Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c cp file1 file2' as USER2 on SERVERNAME.

When using `sudo -i -u USER2 cp` The command you are running is `/bin/bash -c cp`  which you don't have `sudo` permissions for. As you are limited to the command which you have `sudo` permission for: `/bin/cp`.

More info: [man sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sudo.8.html)

> ```
>   -i, --login
>                  Run the shell specified by the target user's password
>                  database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-
>                  specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be
>                  read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed
>                  to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no
>                  command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo
>                  attempts to change to that user's home directory before
>                  running the shell.  The command is run with an environment
>                  similar to the one a user would receive at log in.  The
>                  Command environment section in the sudoers(5) manual
>                  documents how the -i option affects the environment in which
>                  a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.
> ```

Comment: as I understand "file1" file need to have read permission, otherwise ti will give permission error:

cp: cannot open ‘file1’ for reading: Permission denied

Comment: @HaykHovhannisyan - If I've solved your question, please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer